# How to add a .jar file in a Netbeans project specifying a relative path

Tags: java, netbeans, ojdbc

I'm trying to add `ojdbc` and another `.jar` file into my project specifying the relative path such that, if I gave the project to a friend of mine, he would be able to import that project with all necessary `.jar` files already included (and so he doesn't have to pick these files, but the project `.zip` file is "ready-to-use").

Now, as the following image shows:

[image: Adding jar file]

I right click on my project's `Libraries` entry and choose the necessary `.jar` file. But when I try to specify a relative path, Netbeans deny it and so I could not be able to give this project (exported as a `.zip` file using Netbeans' export "function"), as the following image shows:

[image: no option]

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is this the right way to "include" these `.jar` files to the project and then export it and give it to a friend of mine?

Note that my `.zip` project which I import with Netbeans and my `.jar` file are in the same directory (Desktop):

[image]

Comment: Is the JAR file outside your project directory? My guess is that NetBeans can only calculate a relative path if it is under the root project folder.

Comment: My .zip project is into the desktop. My ojdbc file is in a folder into the desktop; so they're on the some directory

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**:

1. Add your `.jar` files as shown in the 1st and 2nd images;
2. Right click on project;
3. Properties;
4. Libraries;
5. Click on that `.jar` file you added;
6. Where is written "Libraries Folder" click Browse and click next.